# Detect diagonal swipe gestures in a UIView

Tags: ios, swipe

I want to detect a two-finger diagonal swipe that starts from the bottom right of the screen to the middle. I tried adding UISwipeGestureRecognizer with direction set as "UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft" but to no vail as the handler is getting invoked even if I start the swipe from the middle of the screen to the top left.

Do I need to sub-class UIGestureRecognizer or can I handle this using touchesBegan and touchesMoved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys!

I ended up writing custom code in touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded and ot works like charm.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    if ([touches count] == 2) {
        CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        if( nowPoint.x >= ALLOWED_X)
            swipeUp = YES;
    }

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}


-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if ([touches count] == 2 && swipeUp) {

        CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
        CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:self];

        if( nowPoint.x <= prevPoint.x && nowPoint.y <= prevPoint.y){
        }
        else {
            swipeUp = NO;
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];

    if ([touches count] == 2 && swipeUp && nowPoint.x <= DELTA_X && nowPoint.y <= DELTA_Y) {
        NSLog(@"Invoke Method");
    }
    swipeUp = NO;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    swipeUp = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the touches method of cause can do every Gesture, the Gesture is supported since ios3.2.
i can give you a simple code , you maybe modify by yourself.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    isTwoFingersBegin = NO;
    isTwoFingersEnd = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *touchView = [touch view];
    if ([touches count] == 2)
    {
        isTwoFingersBegin = YES;
    }

    touchStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    isSwip = YES;
}
#define TOUCH_MOVE_EFFECT_DIST 30
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{   
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    UIView *touchView = [touch view];
    touchEndPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if ([touches count] == 2)
    {
        isTwoFingersEnd = YES;
    }
    CGPoint deltaVector = CGPointMake(touchEndPoint.x - touchStartPoint.x, touchEndPoint.y - touchStartPoint.y);

    if (fabsf(deltaVector.x) > TOUCH_MOVE_EFFECT_DIST
                &&fabsf(deltaVector.y) > TOUCH_MOVE_EFFECT_DIST
                && isSwip &&isTwoFingersBegin&&isTwoFingersEnd) {
                theSwipGesture=RightUpGesture;
            }
    else if (fabsf(deltaVector.x) <- TOUCH_MOVE_EFFECT_DIST
                && fabsf(deltaVector.y) <- TOUCH_MOVE_EFFECT_DIST
                && isSwip&&isTwoFingersBegin&&isTwoFingersEnd) {
                theSwipGesture=LeftDownGesture;
            }

    isSwip = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass it to use `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` anyway.  I'd do `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft` like you said, then set up two `CGRect`s, one for acceptable starting points, one for acceptable end points.  Then use the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` method `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`, and check if the touch point is in the acceptable start rect by using `CGRectContainsPoint()`.  Then (I think) in your `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` subclass, override `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, and check if the end touch is in the acceptable rect.  If it's not, set the state to `UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled` (or however you're supposed to cancel a gesture).  Also make sure the view it's attached to has its `multipleTouchEnabled` property set.  I haven't actually tried this, but something of the sort should do it.  Good luck!

**EDIT**

Actually, if you didn't want to have to worry about specific rect values for the acceptable start/end points, and make it device independent, you could do this:

```
//swap in whatever percentage of the screen's width/height you want in place of ".75f"

//set the origin for acceptable start points
CGFloat startRect_x = self.view.frame.size.width * .75f;
CGFloat startRect_y = self.view.frame.size.height * .75f;

//set the size
CGFloat rectWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - startRect_x;
CGFloat rectHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - startRect_y;

//make the acceptable start point rect
CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(startRect_x, startRect_y, rectWidth, rectHeight);

//set the origin for the accepable end points
CGFloat endRect_x = self.view.center.x - rectWidth/2;
CGFloat endRect_y = self.view.center.y - rectHeight/2;

//make the acceptable end point rect
CGRect endRect = CGRectMake(endRect_x, endRect_y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```
- (void)viewPanned:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGR
{
    CGPoint translation = [panGR translationInView:self];

    CGFloat threshold = self.bounds.size.width/2;

    // Detect
    Direction direction = DirectionUnknown;

    if (translation.x > threshold) {
        if (translation.y > threshold) {
            direction = DirectionBottomRight;
        } else if (translation.y < -threshold) {
            direction = DirectionTopRight;
        } else {
            direction = DirectionRight;
        }
    } else if (translation.x < -threshold) {
        if (translation.y > threshold) {
            direction = DirectionBottomLeft;
        } else if (translation.y < -threshold) {
            direction = DirectionTopLeft;
        } else {
            direction = DirectionLeft;
        }
    } else {
        if (translation.y > threshold) {
            direction = DirectionBottom;
        } else if (translation.y < -threshold) {
            direction = DirectionTop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to map off a group of coordinates on the iPhone's screen where the swipe could potentially start, and another where it could potentially end. Then in the `touchesBegan:` and `touchesMoved:` methods, you could compare the starting and ending points of the swipe and determine whether it qualified as diagonal.