# Detect left and right movement using UILongPressGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

From what I already know from this question [Detecting the direction of PAN gesture in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777281/detecting-the-direction-of-pan-gesture-in-ios) answered by H2CO3, you can detect left or right movement in `UIPanGestureRecognizer` by using:

```
CGPoint vel = [gesture velocityInView:self.view];
if (vel.x > 0)
 {
     // user dragged towards the right
 }
 else
 {
     // user dragged towards the left
 }
```

I want to detect left or right movement when user tap and hold a button similar to code above by using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` when user entered `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` state, but it seems I can't simply using `velocityInView` to make things work in my case.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First set the recognizer's `allowableMovement` to a big value (it's 10 pixels by default). And use the following code

```
-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)g
{
    if (g.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        _initial = [g locationInView:self.view]; // _initial is instance var of type CGPoint
    }
    else if (g.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        CGPoint p = [g locationInView:self.view];
        double dx = p.x - _initial.x;
        if (dx > 0) {
            NSLog(@"Finger moved to the right");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Finger moved to the left");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is continuous, so you'll receive multiples `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`. Use `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` if you only want one notification when the user lifted his finger.