# SwipeAction is Triggering with a Delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe

I have included a swipe gesture in my app to open a side bar when swiped. I am using [XYOrigami](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYOrigami) to achieve the `swipe`. Everything is fine but my problem is the swipe action is triggering after a delay. I swipe and when the swipe is over then after few-millisecond its action is triggering. I want the action to follow the finger motion. Can anyone guid me on this.

I hope i am able to explain my question well. 
I am adding swipe gesture through xib.

Comment: You would need to implement `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: @JakubVano I am using UISwipeGesture. I need to swipe and open a side bar

Comment: Swipe gesture triggers actions only after it has finished. You want "action to follow the finger motion", thus you need pan gesture.

Comment: @JakubVano Can i trigger Pan gesture with single touch motion?

Comment: Sure. Pan gesture is for moving stuff around via touches.

Comment: @JakubVano but my problem is i have left and right both side bar and scrollview on my main page. How will i differentiate between these?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78316/discussion-between-jakub-vano-and-shruti).

Answer (score 0):

To trigger action along with gesture, we can use pangesture. 
But as you said you have a problem that, You have scrollview and you also need to get left or right swipe.

Now I assume, 
**1.** You have vertical scrollview and 
**2.** You want to recongnize left and right gesture.

This can be achieved through velocity.

```
- (void)panGestureRecognized:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view];
    if (velocity.x > 0) {
        NSLog(@"To Right");
    }
    else    {
        NSLog(@"To Left");
    }
}
```

By checking just **x** values it will resolve your scrollbar issue.
And You can also check left or right gesture by its positive or negative value.

**Refer to this answer for more accurate solution.**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552885/1101477